# Sharepoint 2013 authentication prompt continuously

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, authentication, windows-authentication

I've a SharePoint Foundation 2013 installation (I've applied SP1). This SP has authentication based on local user, because this server is outside my LAN and on a cloud server.

So, from my office LAN, when I try to login to my SharePoint website, I continuously receive the authentication form. My credentials are right without doubts.

When I'm at home, I can login from the same computer without problem.

So, I think the difference is the firewall, because at work I have a Gateprotect firewall, instead at home I use only the Windows firewall.

But the question is: is it really this? or I can configure my SharePoint to use different ports/authentication to bypass this problem?

I think it's quite common to have a good firewall but it seems weird to me to open ports each time only for login to a SP site.

What's your opinion?

Comment: Is the site a Trusted Site where you are getting the prompts? Home networks tend to have relaxed browsing settings, so it may cache the credentials compared to the office network.

Comment: Yes, it is saved in IE in "Trusted Sites". The weird thing is that I'm using the same PC, so configurations (of PC) are the same.

Comment: you might want to have a look this link:http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2012/02/sharepoint-keeps-prompting-for-credentials/

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work